# How to show/hide div if last checkbox is checked/unchecked in angular2?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I am working on the angular2 app. In my requirement is create multiple checkboxes using the array and the last checkbox is checked so show the div if the last checkbox is unchecked so hide the div.

**Component.ts:-**

```
peoples: any = [
 { "name":"rahul", "status":false},
 { "name":"rija", "status":false},
 { "name":"roy", "status":false},
 { "name":"ninja", "status":false},
 { "name":"riya", "status":false},
 { "name":"rohit", "status":true},
];
```

**component.html**

```
  <div *ngFor = "let people of peoples">
     <input  type = "checkbox" [value] = 'people?.name' [checked] = "people?.status">
      {{people?.name}}
  </div>

 /****** Hide/show div (if last checkbox is checked so show is div and unchecked so hide this div ******/
 <div>
   <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: try `last` index with `*ngFor`

Comment: use it with `*ngFor` like `*ngFor = "let people of peoples;let last = last;"`. you will get last index of the ngFor from this and you can use this to check if checkbox is last

Comment: @harleen or you can use this too `[hidden]="!peoples[peoples.length - 1].status"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like pardeep jain pointed out, you can use

```html
[hidden]="!peoples[peoples.length - 1].status"
```

but I just want to mention, then use `ngModel`, and when using that, you can also get rid of `[checked]` when using that.

```html
<div *ngFor="let people of peoples">
   <input type="checkbox" [value]="people.name" [(ngModel)]="people.status">
   {{people?.name}}
</div>


<div [hidden]="peoples[peoples.length - 1].status">
  <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
    <!-- Hide/show text here -->
    <div *ngIf="peoples[peoples?.length - 1]?.status">
       <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
```

In the above code sample, if the last element is `checked`(if status is `true`) then showing the below `div`.

**EDIT:**

Change HTML as:

```
<div *ngFor = "let people of peoples;let i = index;">
   <input  type = "checkbox" [value] = 'people?.name' [checked] = "people?.status" (change)="cahngeStatus(i)">
   {{people?.name}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="peoples[5].status">
   <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
</div>
```

Add following function to js:

```
cahngeStatus(index) {
    peoples[index].status = !peoples[index].status;
}
```

We can alternatively do by using `ngModel` by importing `FormsModule`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is not work show error :- Component.html:220 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined

Comment: Peoples array is defined and has data?

Comment: I am asking whether peoples array is defined and has data? Do you understand the `error`? That is because there is no peoples array.

Comment: I understand and This only works on if I change status on the array. But my question is if checked the last checkbox so show div and unchecked last checkbox hide the div. Not change its people array.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora, now understood the problem. When ever you check the element it is not reflected as we are doing one way binding. To achieve your required functionality, we must listen to the change. I will update the code soon.